# How does view synchronizes with the table

Tags: sql, database, view

Assume I created `updatable view`:

```
CREATE VIEW OFFICEINFO AS
SELECT OFFICE, CITY, REGION
FROM OFFICES
```

**Questions**:

1. Will my `OFFICEINFO` reflect changes if I insert new value to
   `OFFICES`?
2. How does synchronization work. Is there any predefined triggers on `OFFICES` table?
3. Can I switch off synchronization?
4. What is "pro" and "contro" of having synchronization between `view` and `table`?

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. No. A view is just a stored select statement. Nothing is stored it just runs the select  statement. 3 N/A 4. N/A. You might be a getting confused with an indexed view (or materialised view)

Comment: "unclear what you're asking" really is ridiculous here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an `oracle` DB, a quick glimpse:

1. Yes
2. No `triggers`, you can imagine a `view` as a *pointer* to a `table`. It reflects the table data in real time, it just store the *query*
3. No, but you can use a `materialized view` as alternative.
4. *Pro*: you can use the `view` as an *aggregator* from table data (or tables if you use a join) ,it does not occupy space in database, *con*: if you change table/s structure the view will become invalid until recompilation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem confused about views.  A view is just a bunch of SQL code that gets plugged into a query when it runs.  The closest equivalent in traditional programming languages is a macro.

So, the view doesn't really exist as a separate entity (with an exception noted below).  Each time the view is referenced, the code that defines the view is inserted into the query.  Hence a view always shows the latest changes to a table, without using triggers or other mechanisms.

The one exception is *materialized views*.  Not all databases support these.  But those that do allow the view to be instantiated as a table.  The database itself takes care of synchronization.  Your question is not about materialized views.  They can be very useful in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you are working on SQL

1. Yes. View is just a pre-complied query
2. (Yes- Partially) .Synchroniztion you have to check manually. If you any operations like (CRUD) with view then Trigger with the Table will intiates
3. No. The view you have created never support for synchronization.
4. Synchronization would be fine to get the latest structure(Schema Level) or else it will leads to mismatched Schema in your View.

I can suggest you to read [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/b4H8260312-Different-Types-of-SQL-Server-Views.html) for better understanding.